# how to find all zip code near by radius using google API

Tags: java, android, google-api

I basically want to retrieve a list of zip code by given radius. Is Google's Geocode API  doing so? I've tried looking into the documentation but not found the information and lots of third party API provide this only specific country, not for all.

Answer (score -1):

Geo Coding will work with address and it will return JSON response which you may parse.
For defined radius, you can apply geocoding

Please review this link.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1

Comment: Google API have no facility for finding zip code within a polygon.